# How to use the | (or) operator in google analytics filter?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I have a filter I want to apply to my google analytics chart embedded in my site. I want to filter ga:pagePathLevel2 to be one of a list of numbers;

Ideally I want it to be something like

```
 'filters' : 'ga:pagePathLevel2==/6|/7|/8',
```

but that doesnt work,  My authorization button doesnt show up after that so apparently something doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a the `=~` syntax to set a [regular expression filter](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference#filters) if you want to match a URL part in several possible forms.

If your case, you could do something like:

```
'filters': 'ga:pagePathLevel2=~^/(6|7|8)'
```

**On an unrelated note:** if your auth button isn't showing up at all, it's almost certainly because you have a syntax error and has nothing to do with the filter syntax. If you open up the developer console, you should see the error being logged.